# What is the "opposite" of request serialization called?

Tags: serialization, request, terminology, resources

For example, if a request is made to a resource and another identical request is made before the first has returned a result, the server returns the result of the first request for the second request as well. This to avoid unnecessary processing on the resource. This is not the same thing as caching/memoization since it only concerns identical requests ongoing in parallel.

Is there a term for the reuse of results for currently ongoing requests to a resource for the purpose of minimizing processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call it request piggybacking.

Comment: Since I don't see it as caching (it's only "cached" during the actual request duration), this is the term that comes closest.

Comment: I disagree. Piggybacking is more about reusing a transport channel or packet to carry **additional** data meant for someone else than the original recipient. Here, it is only about uniquizing the job/task queue. I'd stick to the word "cache/reuse" even though the cache lifespan is efectively zero. Maybe coin up a "zerospan cache" or "instaneous cache". Result-reuse suggested by **nos** is probably the best here.

Comment: I call it piggybacking because of what my implementation looks like. It attaches the second request onto the processing thread of the first request.

Answer (score 2):

That's really just caching/memoization , with a few restrictions - some might call it result-reuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you queue up your requests, the code waiting for the resource can examine the queue to see if there are any identical requests pending and somehow return the same resource for that one too.

Have you done any profiling? I'd bet this is way more work than it is worth.

Comment: Oh, I doubt that (knock on wood). The system in question is written in Erlang where notifications (messages) are very cheap. The resource is a hardware component which is not very fast. Although you are right in that benchmarking should be done before such a mechanism is put in front of a resource.